# Check Multiple Columns for the highest value

Tags: excel

So say I had a table like this that has the score of 3 different teams for the week.

```
Day   Team1 Team2  Team3
Mon     5     2      2
Tue     0     7      7
Wed     6     3      2
Thu     0     0      1 
Fri    13     6      5
```

I want a formula that can find the highest score for the day and mark it on a identical table with a value of 1 and mark the other teams 0.

If there are 2 values that are the highest I want them to both be marked 1.

There will never be day with all 0's

Using the data from the table above my other table would look like this.

```
Day   Team1 Team2  Team3
Mon     1     0      0
Tue     0     1      1
Wed     1     0      0
Thu     0     0      1 
Fri     1     0      0
```

I have a working formula

```
=IF(AND(B2>=$C2,B2>=$D2,B2>=$E2),1,0)
```

I was just hoping there was a better way to write this formula, so that I can drag it across the teams and have it still work.

If I try to drag my formula now. I have to update the formula for each column. Sometimes I might have 20 + teams.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MAX():

```
=IF(B2=MAX($B2:$D2),1,0)
```

Then copy/drag over and down.

[image]

Comment: short, simple, efficient, and quick answer (<4 minutes)...you on lunch Scott? 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd I am always out to lunch.  This is a good distraction as I wait for the code to run.